# 301 редирект c /category.php на /category/

Tags: php, .htaccess

Прбую прописать редирект.

```
RewriteRule ^category/? category.php
```

Но в таком случае HTTP заголовок 200, а нужен 301.

```
RewriteRule ^category/? category.php [R=301,L]
```

Запускает бесконечный редирект.

```
RewriteRule 301 ^category/? category.php
```

Ошибка 500.

Как правильно прописать 301 редирект?

Comment: Попробуйте `RewriteRule ^category/? category.php [R=301,L]`

Comment: `RewriteRule ^category/?$ category.php [R=301,L]` ?

Comment: Если прописать RewriteRule ^category/?$ category.php [R=301,L] - выдает 404